# xamarin-bluetooth-le does not scan devices

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using xamarin-bluetooth-le to make BluetoothLE client side on Xamarin.
I searched few of BluetoothLE package (sample code is work fine).
Thus, I have choosed xamarin-bluetooth-le.

In fact, sample code work fine.
However, I am simplify sample code without view, becuse I am not need View and binding is not need.

However xamarin-bluetooth-le does not scan device by the simplify code.

First question:
In sample of xamarin-bluetooth-le, an event named DeviceDiscovered is need assign two times?(one is DeviceListViewModel constructor, the other is scan method).

Second(main) question:
Why xamarin-bluetooth-le does not scan device by below codes?

Environment is
Visual Studio 2019   16.10.0
Xamarin              16.10.000.228
Plugin.BLE           2.1.2
Other                newest

Below is code:
BluetoothClient.cs

```
using Plugin.BLE;
using Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Contracts;
using Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.EventArgs;
using Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Extensions;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PlugInBLETest.NetowrkModels
{
    public class BluetoothBLEClient
    {
        private IAdapter Adapter;
        private IBluetoothLE Current;
        public ObservableCollection<IDevice> DeviceList { get; }
        private CancellationTokenSource CancelSource;

        public BluetoothBLEClient()
        {
            Current = CrossBluetoothLE.Current;
            Adapter = CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter;

            Adapter.DeviceDiscovered += OnDeviceDiscovered;
            Adapter.ScanTimeoutElapsed += OnScanTimeoutElapsed;
            Adapter.DeviceDisconnected += OnDeviceDisconnected;
            Adapter.DeviceConnectionLost += OnDeviceConnectionLost;

            DeviceList = new ObservableCollection<IDevice>();
        }


        public async Task SearchDevices()
        {
            if (Current.State == BluetoothState.Off)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                DeviceList.Clear();

                foreach (var connectedDevice in Adapter.ConnectedDevices)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await connectedDevice.UpdateRssiAsync();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }

                CancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                Adapter.ScanMode = ScanMode.LowLatency;

                Adapter.ScanTimeout = 30000;

                //Adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) => DeviceList.Add(a.Device);
                Adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) =>
                {
                    DeviceList.Add(a.Device);
                };
                await Adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync(CancelSource.Token);

                var temp = DeviceList.Count;
            }
            return;
        }

        private void OnDeviceConnectionLost(object sender, DeviceErrorEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void OnDeviceDisconnected(object sender, DeviceEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void OnScanTimeoutElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void OnDeviceDiscovered(object sender, DeviceEventArgs args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.pluginbletest">
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <application android:label="PlugInBLETest.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you ask for the location permission?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Essentials has a [permissions feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=android) that will allow you to check for and request permission for access to the location data

After Marshmallow you have to prompt for the user for permission -> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/